# Combining CompletableFutures into a tree-like Structure

Tags: java, functional-programming, monads, java-8

I'm currently experimenting with Java 8's Future API and in the Core CompleteableFuture. I know it is a monad, so it should have a bind-Operator.

Now the idea is that I have a tree of abstract Operations k, e.g. like this:

```
O --- > O3 ---> O4 ---> o5
  O ---> o2 --/
```

I want to "merge" `O3` and `O2` into a new Operation  `O4 = (O3 o O2) (t) = O2(O3(t))`. 
My idea is that I'm e.g. in `O2` and want to say: Merge the current node with `O3` and return a new node consisting of the concatenated operations.
Unfortunately I've tried for the whole night now and I cannot figure it out.
Also, for unknown reasons using the operator like `O1.mergeWith(O2).mergeWith(O3)` triggers the apply method twice for a singe invocation.

The goal is to create a new function composed of other functions, so I can defer the calulation as far as possible.

```
public abstract class Operation<T,R> {
  // The value a
  private final CompletableFuture<R> future;

// Executes the operation on t and returns something (maybe different) of type R
  protected abstract R apply(T t);

// Gets the value of the future of this operation
  public R get() throws Exception {
    return future.get();
  }

  protected Operation(Supplier<T> s) {
    future =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(s).thenApplyAsync(transform());
  }

  protected Operation(CompletableFuture<R> f) {
    future = f;
  }


  CompletableFuture<R> createTargetFuture(R _value) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> _value);
  }

  <S> Operation<T,S> mergeWith(Operation<R,S> _other) {
    CompletableFuture<S> _result = future.thenComposeAsync(
      // Method is synchronous, but is run async :) We need the createTargetFuture,         otherwise we cannot turn the constant t into a producer.
      (t) -> _other.createTargetFuture(_other.apply(t)));
      //transform()).thenApplyAsync(_other.transform());
    return new Operation<T, S>(_result) {
      @Override
      protected S apply(T t) {
        // What to put here
        return null;
      }
    };
  }

  protected Function<T,R> transform(){
    return this::apply;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Your entire `Operation` class looks like you are adding a functionality to `CompletableFuture` which it already provides on it’s own.

If you have a `Supplier<T> s` and want to defer its execution you can do `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(s)` as you already know.

Now if you want to apply a `Function<T,R> f` to the defered result of a `CompletableFuture<T> a` simply use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->f.apply(a.join()))`.

And the same works for two `CompletableFuture`s and a `BiFunction`: `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->f.apply(a.join(),b.join()))`

If you feel like needing to wrap the operations in some sort of support code, you can create utility methods like these:

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> create(Supplier<T> s) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(s);
}
public static <T,R> CompletableFuture<R> create(
  Function<T,R> f, CompletableFuture<T> a) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->f.apply(a.join()));
}
public static <T,U,R> CompletableFuture<R> create(
  BiFunction<T,U,R> f, CompletableFuture<T> a, CompletableFuture<U> b) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->f.apply(a.join(),b.join()));
}
```

Then you can happily perform async operations like:

```
int i=create((a,b)->a+b, create(()->42),create(()->100)).join();
```

But, of course, the same thing would work without any support methods as well:

```
int i=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->42).join()
  + CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->100).join() ).join();
```

or

```
int j=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->42).thenApplyAsync(
    a-> a + CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->100).join() ).join();
```

Comment: An Operation is an abstract class where subclasses can implement stuff like "take an image, resize it and return the resized image". So there will be more functionality than just the CompleteableFuture part in the end.

Comment: You did not explain why you need the operations you describe to be implemented in a subclass of `Operation` rather than a simple `Function<T,R>`. At the moment you have over forty lines of code adding no benefit to the `CompletableFuture` but introducing errors. Maybe you should focus on that “more functionality”: just remove the erroneous code and create a *simple* wrapper. If you let it implement `Supplier` you can use the code fragments of my answer without any change…

Comment: Thanks for your efforts :) I reconsidered everything and you gave some  good starting points.